# Linux/Unix Find Command

Tags: linux, unix

- This works fine: `find . -name "skr[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].rtf"
  -type f`
- This does not work: `find . -name "skr[0-9]{5}.rtf" -type f`

Could anyone please explain and give me something similar to second version of the command.

Comment: There is not a single `find` command. Do you mean specifically GNU `find`?

Comment: yes, sorry i should have mentioned..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `{5}` is a syntax from *extended regular expressions* not from *shell globbing*. It is not valid with `-name`.

You can use `-regex` instead of `-name` with some find versions (GNU). In that case your pattern have to match the whole path, be careful with `*` and `?` and `.` as they have different meanings in regular expressions.

The repetition count syntax is part of "extended" RE, so you need to use -E (with find variants which actually support it):

```
find -E . -regex '.+/skr[0-9]{5}\.rtf' -type f
```

On Mac you need to install GNU findtools if you want such comfort:

```
brew install findutils --default-names
```

On some systems you can try `gfind` instead of `find`.

Comment: Could you please suggest some command similar to second version?

Comment: could you explain -regex usage in context of this example, i am newbie to linux commands that's why asking.

Comment: @user2132128 Well, as a newbie its best to forget about REs :) I added the example which works, as you can see it is not shorter as your initial correct version, so don't bother... (if you are curious check out a regex tutorial and keep in mind that ".+/" means "one or more characters ending with slash.

Comment: @user2132128 i typically read man or [info pages](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Regular-Expressions). There is a good O'Reily Book on [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do)